# Logback Error Occurred when Migrating to Java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, logback

I'm currently migrating from Java 8 to Java 11. I'm using Spring boot 2.2.7 and Maven 3.6.1. I was able to build my project perfectly without errors but when I tried to start my application, it throws logback errors:

```
23:54:33,407 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
23:54:33,408 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
23:54:33,408 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/workspace/applicationtest/target/classes/logback.xml]
23:54:33,410 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
23:54:33,410 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/Users/rock/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/tess4j/tess4j/3.2.1/tess4j-3.2.1.jar!/logback.xml]
23:54:33,410 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/C:/workspace/applicationtest/target/classes/logback.xml]
23:54:33,509 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
23:54:33,517 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:38 - no applicable action for [springProperty], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProperty]]
23:54:33,517 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@7:30 - no applicable action for [springProfile], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile]]
23:54:33,517 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@8:58 - no applicable action for [springProperty], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][springProperty]]
```

This is the logging part of my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It worked fine when I was still using Java 8. I've also tried excluding the logback but still no luck. The jre that I was using was the one generated using jlink.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Also encountered an issue with logback on Java 11. Whatever the issue is, they seem to have fixed it in the 1.3.0 line (still in alpha).